# How can I generate check sum code in dart?

Tags: dart, crc

I want to use PayMaya EMV Merchant Presented QR Code Specification for Payment Systems everything is good except CRC i don't understand how to generate this code.
that's all exist about it ,but i still can't understand how to generate this .
The checksum shall be calculated according to [ISO/IEC 13239] using the polynomial '1021' (hex) and initial value 'FFFF' (hex). The data over which the checksum is calculated shall cover all data objects, including their ID, Length and Value, to be included in the QR Code, in their respective order, as well as the ID and Length of the CRC itself (but excluding its Value).

Following the calculation of the checksum, the resulting 2-byte hexadecimal value shall be encoded as a 4-character Alphanumeric Special value by converting each nibble to an Alphanumeric Special character.

Example: a CRC with a two-byte hexadecimal value of '007B' is included in the QR Code as "6304007B".

Comment: There are a several third-party packages that provide functions to compute CRC checksums (https://pub.dev/packages?q=crc).  You also can try to implement it yourself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#CRC-32_algorithm

Comment: i know this package but what is the input like the example here  https://pub.dev/packages/crclib     new Crc32Zlib().convert(UTF8.encode('123456789')) == 0xCBF43926
 what is (123456789)

Comment: In that example, '123456789` is a `String` that is encoded into UTF-8-encoded `List<int>` (actually a `Uint8List`) by [`utf8.encode`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-convert/Utf8Codec-class.html). `crclib`'s [`convert`](https://pub.dev/documentation/crclib/latest/crclib/ParametricCrc/convert.html) function takes a `List<int>` (a list of bytes) as input.

Comment: so ,how can i get it or calculated it

Answer (score 1):

The CRC for ISO/IEC 13239 is this [CRC-16/ISO-HDLC](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/16.htm#crc.cat.crc-16-ibm-sdlc), per the notes in that catalog. This implements that CRC and prints the check value `0x906e`:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

int crc16ISOHDLC(Uint8List bytes) {
  int crc = 0xffff;
  for (var b in bytes) {
    crc ^= b;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      crc = (crc & 1) != 0 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8408 : crc >> 1;
  }
  return crc ^ 0xffff;
}

void main() {
  Uint8List msg = Uint8List.fromList([0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39]);
  print("0x" + crc16ISOHDLC(msg).toRadixString(16));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This converts a string to its UTF-8 representation as a sequence of bytes, and prints out the 16-bit Cyclic Redundancy Check of those bytes (CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE).

```
int crc16_CCITT_FALSE(String data) {
  int initial = 0xFFFF; // initial value
  int polynomial = 0x1021;   // 0001 0000 0010 0001  (0, 5, 12)

  Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(data));

  for (var b in bytes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      bool bit = ((b >> (7-i) & 1) == 1);
      bool c15 = ((initial >> 15 & 1) == 1);
      initial <<= 1;
      if (c15 ^ bit) initial ^= polynomial;
    }
  }

  return initial &= 0xffff;
}
```

Comment: That is the wrong CRC for ISO/IEC 13239. You implemented what is known as the false CCITT 16-bit CRC, which shifts up. Furthermore, the CRC for ISO/IEC 13239 is not the true 16-bit CCITT CRC either (which shifts down)! The one for that standard is CRC-16/ISO-HDLC, which is the true CCITT CRC with an initial value of `0xffff`, and a final exclusive-or of `0xffff`.